# Opening XML file with SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax

I want to open a local xml file to parse it.
So i've this line : `saxReader.parse("file.xml");`
And i've this error `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`
So I try to resolve it by giving a fullpath something like C:/.../file.xml
But there is the same problem.

Where do I put the file.xml in the project to resolve the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `saxReader` an instance of `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser`? How exactly do you call `parse`? There isn't such a method with one parameter, you have to supply a handler as well. When passing in a String for the file, that String must be a URI to the file. Learn about URI syntax for the proper form. I think it'd be much better to use a variant of the method that takes a `File`, `InputStream` or `InputSource` after you've located the file via conventional means.

Comment: As @G_H already pointed out, please provide more code (and the exception stacktrace).

Comment: `saxReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader("org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser");
    simpleContentHandler = new SimpleContentHandler();
    saxReader.setContentHandler(simpleContentHandler);
    saxReader.parse("file.xml");`

Here is my code

Comment: Ah, it's an `XMLReader`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `XMLReader`. You could use that, but in Java you're probably better off using stuff from the `javax.xml.parsers` package. Create a `SAXParserFactory` using `SAXParserFactory.newInstance()`, configure it, then call `newSAXParser()` on it. Only provide a class name like you do if you absolutely must use that implementation. Otherwise, it is better to let the default lookup mechanism handle that. As for the actual problem, learn the [URI syntax for files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) and use it, or obtain a `File` instance or an `InputStream` or `InputSource` and pass that to the reader or parser.

Comment: Now i'm using SAXParserFactory but I have the same problem.
I tried  with path like : `file:///C:/Java/file.xml`
I tried using `InputSource("file:///C:/Java/file.xml")`

Comment: Hmm, that looks okay, though. Perhaps try with a lower case `c:`. Otherwise, I'd suggest you just create a `File` object with path `C:/Java/file.xml` and use that object. That ought to work if the XML source is always on the local file system.

Comment: Now i'm doing like that :
`String xmlUri = "file:///g:/Java/Guigui/src/file.xml";          
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new FileInputStream( new File(xmlUri)));
inputSource.setSystemId(xmlUri);
xmlReader.parse(inputSource);`
But always having the open failed 10-24 13:13:55.350: V/debug(2014): IOException : /file:/g:/Java/Guigui/src/citation_jour.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Just do `File f = new File("C:/Java/file.xml");` (or whatever path you're using), then use the `SAXParser` method `parse(f, handler)` with your handler. The parser should normally be capable of detecting the encoding. Try to go for the simplest approach in this stuff.

Comment: The problem is still here.
I forgot to mention that I'm working on Android SDK, maybe there is a link with the problem.

Comment: The `java.io.File` class is available there? Maybe a stupid question, but I don't know squat about the Android SDK or runtime. If it does, just create the `File` object with the proper path, then call `exists()` on it and see what that says. This will tell you if the file can be found or not, regardless of XML parsing. Seeing as this is Android, though, I'd wager you'd need a path starting with `/` rather than some volume letter.

Comment: When I do a f.exists() it's return false.
So I think that there is some particular stuff with the path file on the Android SDK.
Thank for your help, and I'm going to search on the official's android documentation :)

Comment: If it can't find the file, the XML parser/reader won't be any more succesful. Find out how to locate the file in Android. I don't know what environment you're programming in, but if it's some sort of Android emulator (I think that's what the SDK offers), you probably won't have any success trying to load a file that's on your computer's file system. It'll likely need to be in the (possibly virtual) Android file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a string to XMLReader.parse(), it should be a fully-resolved (i.e. absolute) URL. file.xml is not an absolute URL (it's relative). `c:\dir\dir\file.xml` is not an absolute URL either - it's a Windows filename. If you don't understand URLs and aren't used to working with them, it's simpler to pass a Java file: `parse(new InputSource(new File('file.xml')))`

Comment: Been saying that for a while. But apparently it's Android SDK. I haven't ever developed with that so I'm not gonna guess what you can and can't do there.